# Flick an image from an iPad to another screen

Tags: ios, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if the following has ever been done before, ideally in unity.

What I want is to be able to take an image I have on my iPad and send it to a screen to be displayed with a flick gesture. Much like what you do with a window on a computer with dual monitors.

You drag it, and it instantly appears on the other monitor.

if this hasn't been done before, how would you go about making this possible? I know that it is going to require a fair deal of networking if I'm to pass an image from one device to another.

Comment: What have you googled about the parts that you *can* solve? eg registering the flick gesture - or showing an image on a screen? Your question is extremely broad - and it would hep us if you can narrow it down to just the parts you don't know how to do.

Comment: This question is over a year old and has an accepted answer....

Comment: Yes. But Stack Overflow is forever... and this one just hit the review-queue. This comment is there to show other people that find your question - how they should ask a question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Monobehavior

[RPC]
void ShowImage(byte[] data) {
...
}

another computer:
networkView.RPC("ShowImage", RPCMode.All, data)

is that what you want?